# How to parse rows in my txt file properly using perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I hope to parse a txt file that looks like this:

```
A a, b, c
B e
C f, g
```

The format I hope to get is:

```
A a
A b
A c
B e
C f
C g
```

I tried this:

```
perl -ane '@s=split(/\,/, $F[1]); foreach $k (@s){print "$F[0] $k\n";}' txt.txt
```

but it only works when there's no space after commas. In the original file, there is a space after each comma. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for map { tr/,//rd } @F[1..$#F]' input.txt
A a
A b
A c
B e
C f
C g
```

Use auto-split mode on whitespace like normal, and for each element of an [array slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of `@F` from the second field to the last one, remove any commas (I used `tr//d`, the more usual `s///` works too, of course) and print it with the first field prepended.

Comment: @shennnnn Change the space in the print to a comma: `print "$F[0],$_"`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, don't use `-a` because it splits too much.

```
perl -le'@F = split(" ", $_, 2); print "$F[0] $_" for split(/,\s*/, $F[1])'
```